# When adding a UITableView to an existing ViewController with a JTCalendar view up top, the table covers the entire view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently using the [JTCalendar](https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar) calendar control to show a calendar grid on the top half of my view controller. Before I attempt to add a table, the calendar view takes up the top half, and the bottom half is empty.

After I add the code for the `UITableView`, which I want to be displayed in the bottom half, the table is now taking up the entire view, rather than just fitting into the bottom half. I've set up the table view like so:

**ViewController.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "JTCalendar.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<JTCalendarDataSource, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JTCalendarMenuView *calendarMenuView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JTCalendarContentView *calendarContentView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *calendarContentViewHeight;
@property (strong, nonatomic) JTCalendar *calendar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *agendaTableArray;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.calendar = [JTCalendar new];

    // All modifications on calendarAppearance have to be done before setMenuMonthsView and setContentView
    // Or you will have to call reloadAppearance
    {
        self.calendar.calendarAppearance.calendar.firstWeekday = 1;
        self.calendar.calendarAppearance.dayCircleRatio = 9. / 10.;
        self.calendar.calendarAppearance.ratioContentMenu = 1.;
    }

    ////
    // Initialize Day Agenda table
    UITableView *agendaTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    agendaTable.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    agendaTable.delegate = self;
    agendaTable.dataSource = self;
    [agendaTable reloadData];

    [self.view addSubview: agendaTable];
    /////

    [self.calendar setMenuMonthsView:self.calendarMenuView];
    [self.calendar setContentView:self.calendarContentView];
    [self.calendar setDataSource:self];
}
```

What's causing it to take up the entire view? I made sure to have it be a subview, but that doesn't seem to be working. Did I set up the table incorrectly in any way?

Comment: I can clearly see in your code that you are giving frame [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] to your agendaTable, try by setting proper frame here

Comment: seems to be an NSCopyAndPasteError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing the tableview with a fullscreen frame, and haven't told it to shrink down to the height you want. Try applying a fixed height constraint with the height you want, then add constraints to the left, right, and bottom sides of the tableview.

Apple has lots of documentation on how to add constraints programmatically: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html

Or you can move all this stuff into the interface builder and change sizes/constraints that way.